# Jackson serialization from Object to Xml for Character data type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I have a simple pojo such as

```
public class XYZ {
   private String name;
   private Character gender;
}
```

We use this pojo as the Entity response from Rest API (Spring Rest Controller) which produces produces both MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` and    MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE

The JSON output is fine but the XML output is not expected. 'gender' field as Character type has 'numeric value' like 89, 90 ... things like that, not like 'Y' or 'N' (just an example)

The issue happens if we have 'Accept' header as application/xml

Is this behavior expected one from Jackson library or not? I'm using Spring 5.0.x

Thanks

Comment: A Java `char`/`Character` _is_ a numeric type. JSON doesn't have "character", just "number" and "string".

Comment: Do you have the following dependency in your project? groupId: "com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat " and artifactId: "jackson-dataformat-xml"?

Comment: I seeing jackson-dataformat-cbor

Comment: You may want to try adding "jackson-dataformat-xml", I tried it and for me, new Character('Y') is being rendered as Y in XML format

Comment: Thank you. Let I try it

Comment: how did the change go?

Comment: Oh sorry. I totally forgot to update back here. Thanks @LionelCichero. It is working as expected.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

That way Jackson will know how to convert any special characters to the corresponding XML format.